# ¿Cómo obtener elementos de un HashMap en otra clase en Java?

Tags: java, android

Que tal aún no entiendo muy bien lo de las Interfaces, espero y me puedan ayudar de alguna manera, tengo la siguiente Interface:

```
public interface interface {

HashMap get_data();
```

Tengo una clase `persona`donde lleno el HashMap con datos de un formulario:

```
@Override
public HashMap get_data() {
    validate_data();
    if (validate_data()) {
        HashMap<String, Object> a_hash = new HashMap<>();
        a_hash.put("numero", numberSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
        a_hash.put("nombre", nameEditText.getText().toString());
        a_hash.put("descripcion", descriptiondNumberEditText.getText().toString();
        return a_hash;
    } else
        return new HashMap();
}
```

Ahora quisiera saber como obtener algunos de esos datos en otra clase `detallePersona`:

```
public class detallePersona{

   public void detalle_persona(){
      person = new Person(nombre,descripcion); // <== Aquí quiero meter los datos

    }
}
```

Clase Person

```
public class Person{

    private String nombre;
    private String descipcion;


    //Más código

}
```

Se que para obtenerlos en la misma clase es `a_hash.get("nombre")` pero en otra clase no tengo idea, una disculpa si es fácil.

Comment: cuando dices clase te refieres a una funcion o metodo, porque esa es la sensacion que meda ami, que estas confundiendo clase con lo anterior, pues dices que puede obterlo en la misma clase usando -> a_hash.get("nombre") y por lo que veo es scope/alcance de a_hash es local, por eso pregunto si tienes claro el concepto de class y metodo. Saludos

Comment: pero si esta todo bien, podrias tratar de hacer, person.get_data().get("nombre"); , por ejemplo sin modificar mucho lo que ya tienes

Comment: Por supuesto que tengo claro que es una clase y un método, no se si te diste cuenta que la clase se llama detallePersona y el método detalle_persona, y lo que dices, no me funciona, ah eso se debe mi pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Ya edité la pregunta, le agruegué cosas para que sea entendible

Comment: si validate_data() es true, te hara el return de a_hash, si no hara el return de uno vacio igual es ese el error. Saludos

Comment: intente poner las clases como las esta usando porque habla de interfaces pero no veo que Persona la implemente, y seria estar basandose en ideas de que si lo hace pero no lo puso, y eso crea confuciones aunque para este caso no influya mucho o si, tambien tiene la clase detalle_persona incompleta, creo que ponerlas enteras o por lo menos lo que ponga lo que esta usando, Tambien podria poner la desde donde se esta creando detallepersona si es que lo esta creando o quiere hacer una llamada estatica o que es lo que esta haciendo, si puede poner el log tambien seria bueno .Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que deseas es simplemente tener acceso a la información puedes hacerlo pasando el HashMap en el constructor de la otra clase

```
public class DetallePersona {
// ....
private HashMap<String, Object> hash;

public DetallePersona(HashMap<String, Object> hash) {
    this.hash = hash;
}

public void detallePersona(){
    String nombre = hash.get("nombre").toString();
    String descripcion = hash.get("descripcion").toString();
    Person person = new Person(nombre,descripcion); // <== Aquí quiero meter los datos
    //hacer algo con el objeto person ...
    }
}
```

Otra opción es (si el detalle debe ser reutilizado) crear un método `static` con el `HashMap` como argumento

```
public static void detallePersona(HashMap<String, Object> hash){
    //obtener los keys deseados
}
```

Ojo que el nombre de la clase debe iniciar con mayúscula y el nombre de lo métodos debe ser escrito en **camelCase**.
Hay muchas posibilidades para hacerlo, sería bueno detallar un poco más el objetivo final para dar una solución más apropiada.
Espero te ayude.
Saludos!

Comment: Gracias, tomaré su primer respuesta :D

Answer (score 0):

si usted quiere obtener un data desde otra clase sobre otro objeto puede hacer algo así:

```
public void detalle_persona(String key){

      person = new Person(nombre,descripcion); // <== Aquí quiero meter los datos

      //aqui obtiene el objeto si validate es true y 
      //la clave corresponde con alguna en el hash
      person.get_data().get(key);

    }
```

así puede recuperar el objeto, en base a lo que usted tiene, ahora si recupera el objeto si desea almacenarlo solo tendría que asignarlo `Objeto myObjeto = person.get_data().get(key);`

---

O esta forma Pseudo code:

```
public class detallePersona{

   //..contructor/es ect

   private Person person; //sample

   public void detalle_persona(){
      person = new Person(nombre,descripcion); // <== Aquí quiero meter los datos

    }

    public void consultar(String key){

         Object myObject;

         if(person.get_data().containsKey(key)){
             myObject = person.get_data().get(key);
         } 
         //comprobar que no sea null y hacerlo que se requiera,
         //si se quiere devolver se ajusta el método para que haga el return etc
    }
}
```

la llamada seria algo así según su código:

```
detallePersona dPersona = new elConstructorQueUstedTenga();
dPersona.detalle_persona();
//cosas que hace y en algun punto quiere consultar, si quiere hacer un return ajustar el metodo ect
dPersona.consultar("nombreAConsultar");
```

---

Puede que le sea util [containsKey](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#containsKey(java.lang.Object))

Comment: @megaonly Con lo que puedo leer y entiendo esto es lo unico que le puedo contestar, pues no dice que es lo que quiere hacer, ni de donde lo quiere llamar/consultar o si quiere tener un metodo que consulte sobre el objeto creado. Saludos